# How to wrap email address in span tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a paragraph, the content is automatically generated, I cannot edit the HTML directly. The paragraph will always end in an email address then a question mark. I want to bold the email address. Here is the HTML:

```
<p class="unsub-main">Do you want to stop receiving emails from us to the email address noreply@noreply.com?</p>
```

I would like to bold the email address only. I tried the following:

```
    $('.unsub-main:contains').html(function(){  
    // separate the text by spaces
    var text= $(this).text().split(' ');
    // drop the last word and store it in a variable
    var last = text.pop();
    // join the text back and if it has more than 1 word add the span tag
    // to the last word
    return text.join(" ") + (text.length > 0 ? ' <span class="last">'+last+'</span>' : last);   
});
```

Can I wrap the last string before the question mark in the paragraph in a span tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code almost works. All you need is to remove the `:contains` selector, which is used to filter only those elements that contain something. Its syntax is `$(":contains(text)")`, but you didn't define the text to find in the brackets, so `$('.unsub-main:contains')` matches nothing. Either remove `:contains` or  use it with text in brackets

```js
$('.unsub-main').html(function(){  
    // separate the text by spaces
    var text = $(this).text().split(' ');
    // drop the last word and store it in a variable
    var last = text.pop();
    // join the text back and if it has more than 1 word add the span tag
    // to the last word
    return text.join(" ") + (text.length > 0 ? ' <span class="last">'+last+'</span>' : last);   
});
```

```css
.last {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="unsub-main">Do you want to stop receiving emails from us to the email address noreply@noreply.com?</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need javascript for this, you don't even need CSS. Any reason you can't just wrap it in strong tags like this?

```
<p class="unsub-main">Do you want to stop receiving emails from us to the email address <strong>noreply@noreply.com</strong>?</p>
```

or better yet make the email clickable with a mailto: href and also bold:

```
<p class="unsub-main">Do you want to stop receiving emails from us to the email address <strong><a href="mailto:noreply@noreply.com">noreply@noreply.com</a></strong>?</p>
```

Simple jquery way:

```
var boldLink = '<p class="unsub-main">Do you want to stop receiving emails from us to the email address <strong><a href="mailto:noreply@noreply.com">noreply@noreply.com</a></strong>?</p>'
$('.unsub-main').html(boldLink)
```

Comment: I do not have direct access to the HTML, it is automatically generated. I can only edit the paragraph via JS

Comment: ah I see, then you need js

Comment: The above will not work because the content is automatically generated, the email address changes based on who is unsubscribing. The above script will hardcode the email address.

Comment: and you can't add the user email as variable on load?

Comment: Then go with @Kirill Simonov's answer :)